# Permission denied error on accessing OneDrive file from a process on MacOS

Tags: macos, plist, onedrive, launch-daemon

On Mac with a process started with /bin/launchctl load -w /Library/LaunchDaemons/ex.plist tries to open the offline OneDrive file ( Open - c system call ). It returns errno 13 ( Permission denied error ).  Process or app directly started without launchctl can open the file ( On open file will get automatically downloaded ).
Why cant process launched from launchctl cannot open the file ? Is there any configuration available to make it happen on OneDrive or in plist file Or OneDrive explicitly dont allow such process to open the file ?

Comment: Is this supposed to be a launch *daemon* (runs as root), in which case you need to load it with `sudo launchctl load ...`; or a launch *agent* (runs as logged-in user), in which case it belongs in /Library/LaunchAgents/? Also, where is this file it's supposed to open, and is it subject to [privacy protection](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/332673/what-and-how-does-macos-mojave-implement-to-restrict-applications-access-to-pers)?

Comment: @GordonDavisson, Thank you for the response. Yes the process is running as root and full disk assess has been enabled for the process. This process can open all the files, only issue is coming for one drive on demand files. If the file was downloaded then process is able to open.